# Why isn't there a self answer option on the app?

Tags: feature-request, self-answer, mobile-app, instant-self-answer

On mobile, it's very accessible and easy to use, but I have one problem. There is no self-answer option when posting a question so I have to pre-write it and copy/paste it over or doing on the mobile full site. I propose we have a self-answer option on the app.

Will self-answer be allowed on mobile in the future?

Comment: Can't you just post the question, then post the self answer?

Comment: "Mobile" and "app" aren't the same thing. Please clarify which one or that both is what you're talking about.